# Angular 2 request headers automaticaly converted to lowercase in webpack

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 with webpack. 
I am facing an issue with the first letter of the header parameters which are automatically converted to lower case. Eg.

`Accept': 'application/json, text/plain`

converts to

`accept':'application/json, text/plain`

> pakage.json

```
{
  "name": "life-inventory",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Life lazy loading",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-materialize": "^6.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "vue-router": "^2.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.2.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.17",
    "angular2-materialize": "^6.7.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

My request file is

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, URLSearchParams, Response} from "@angular/http";

private headers = new Headers({
        'content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
         });

addToken() {
        if (jQuery.jStorage.get('currentUser')) {
            this.token = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.jStorage.get('currentUser')).token;
            this.headers.set('csToken', this.token);
            this.headers2.set('csToken', this.token);
            this.username = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.jStorage.get('currentUser')).username;
        }
    }

getDashboard(): Promise<Gast[]> {
        this.addToken();
        const url = `${this.apiUrl}/Dashboard?format=json`;
        debugger
        return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Gast[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I have tried using the `.set`  & `.append` methods of header, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter if your header is in camelcase or upper. Ideally it should not matter. Http implementation should be case insensitive. If it does matter in your case check with the backend team if they have implemented the codes correctly for apis.

Comment: Any way to pass headers in camelcase ?

Comment: write an interceptor and you can then even pass your custom headers without any issue.